# Route [login] not defined. Laravel Sanctum with React as SPA

Tags: reactjs, laravel, laravel-9, laravel-sanctum

I am using Laravel sanctum to authenticate my SPA created in React. Once I login

`Login.jsx`

```
const response = await loginUser(authDispatchContext, payload)
if (response){
    toast.success("Log in successful, Redirecting.")
    navigate("/")
}
```

the dashboard component is shown without any redirection, and an API is being called

`Dashboard.jsx`

```
import axios from "../config/axios";
....

const response = await axios.get(url + path)
setListings(response.data.data)
```

my `axios.js` is

```
import axios from 'axios';
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
const user = localStorage.getItem("user") ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")) : null
console.log(user)
if(user){
    axios.defaults.headers.common = {'Authorization': `Bearer ${user.accessToken}`}
}
export default axios;
```

After the successful login I get the following error [screenshot](https://ibb.co/pxSghc1).

My request headers [screenshot](https://ibb.co/Tgzx5hs)

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Authorization: Bearer 37|wOutmLsOgO3MPuuoJf13lmlbYTW4cQ3eax1FppGU
```

I can see that Authorization header is being set properly and Bearer token is set. But Laravel server is not authenticating the request and sending back a redirect to login page but I am expecting json response.

**When i reload the page, it works normally as expected. Why this weird issue without reload? Can you please point me in the right direction. **

All of my routes except `login` and `register` in `api.php` are protected with `auth:sanctum` middleware

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(function () {
...
Route::get("crypto/all", [Crypto::class, "all"]);
Route::get("crypto/meta/{currencyId}", [Crypto::class, "meta"]);

...
});
```

**Update**

If I directly include the Bearer token with my request, then everything works fine as well.

```
const response = await axios.get(url + path, {
                headers: {
                    "Authorization": "Bearer " + token
                }
            })
```

Comment: Show your web.php that has the `login` route

Comment: use accept: **application/json** in header